# Understanding the “Treasury auction results” press release

Tags: bonds

This is the press release for a recent 30-Year bond auction results:
https://www.treasurydirect.gov/instit/annceresult/press/preanre/2020/R_20201112_5.pdf

I cannot figure out how the price is calculated. It is not the coupon divided by the yield. So what is it?

Comment: Did you assume half the annual coupon every 6 months? I don't see the mean yield (only high, low, median) so I don't think you can calculate the mean price.

Comment: This page has yield conventions.  http://www.derivativepricing.com/blogpage.asp?id=12 It includes a “US Treasury” yield convention. I have not dug around the Treasury documentation to validate that this is the exact convention. In any event, it’s going to be close to the standard market convention.

Comment: H2ONaCl: I just tried calculating for two 6 month coupon. I get a total coupon payment of 1.6316015625$ for a price of 97.119140625.